# select statement stores null in variable

Tags: mysql, sql

[**SQL Fiddle Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75455/1)
(You can see my schema and data on above link)

I have three tables

1.register, 2.user_plan, 3.network

I have a trigger after insertion on user_plan. Insertion in network is done through this trigger

I have `uid=4` in user_plan table

I have `id=2` where `right_mem=4` in register table

So I can not understand why

```
set userid=(select id from register where right_mem=my_userid);
```

This query gives me user_id = `NULL` but I should get user_id= `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `my_userid` variable to null a few lines up. Therefore your query is not looking for `right_mem = 4`.